# Copy Paste Dynamic Range Underneath Last Row - VBA

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I am running a PPC account for a real estate company.

Every week I receive a data-set with a dynamic number of rows illustrating regions and property types. The columns contain provinces, cities & suburbs with the associated property type and 2 synonyms:

[image: Data Sample]

I am creating a macro that will generate keywords based on each of the 2 synonyms so I need the macro to copy and paste all the data 1 row underneath the last row

Comment: Nice to hear what you need but (1) you didn't ask a question and this is a question/answer site and (2) this is not a free code writing service. So please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add the code you already have. Then ask a *specific* question to your code. E.g. describe what it does and where you got stuck or got any errors and where they occur. For a good start you may search for how to find the last used row of a worksheet and you will find many answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll spend some more time polishing the question then.